# Network Status Down after HyperV to Azure Failover

Tags: networking, azure, failover

I was hoping someone could help.

I've setup a recovery services vault protecting a HyperV site.

Everything seems to be working as expecting in terms of replication, but when performing a failover the test server has no network connectivity.

I've checked everything along the lines of DHCP, DNS, Windows Firewall, RDP, Azure VM Agent, NSG, etc.

It actually seems more that it is a 'connection' problem with the NIC on the Azure VM - as shown in the Serial Output below;

"networkAdapters":[{"name":"Ethernet 2","status":"Down","macAddress":"00-0D-3A-4F-0C-79","ipProperties":[{"protocolVersion":4,"address":"169.254.116.15","isDhcpEnabled":true},{"

Status - Down and failed DHCP address IP.

The Boot Diagnostics screenshot also shows the server logon page with a red cross on the network icon.

I've tried removing the NIC, adding another, changing the IP and also re-deploying to another Azure host, however i'm not able to resolve.

In the past when manually migrating a HyperV image I haven't seen this problem so I was curious if it's common or I have hit a bug of some kind?

Can anyone help with some advice.

Thanks.

MD